# CSS overriding JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the contactform originally hidden when the page is loaded, so contactform is to be hidden originally to do this in CSS i did:

```
#contactform{
display: none;
}
```

now in the HTML I have:

`<div class="contactme" ><a href="#contactnav" onclick="someFunc()">Message me!</a></div>`

and onclicking the message me it calls the function 'someFunc' the function hides the contactinfo but displays the contactform, the function is:

```
function someFunc() {
document.getElementById('contactinfo').style.display='none';
document.getElementsByID('contactform').style.display='block';
}
```

It hides the contactinfo perfectly as expected, however it doesn't show the contactform. I believe this could be because the CSS is overriding the function, is there any way to stop it from doing so and get it working as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is bad function name, correctly is small "d" and "Element" instead of "Elements"

```
document.getElementById('contactform').style.display='block';
                  ^   ^
```

Comment: Oh, that was daft of me! Thank you for that:)

Answer (score 1):

in your code `document.getElementsByID` is mention not `document.getElementById` USE THIS code:

```
function someFunc() {
document.getElementById('contactinfo').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('contactform').style.display='block';
}
```